# Line bundles with vanishing cohomology on Calabi-Yau manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, line-bundles, calabi-yau

Suppose we have some line bundle $L(D)$ on Calabi-Yau threefold. Let's call this line bundle "rigid" if $H^0(X,L(D)) \simeq \mathbb{C}$ and $H^i(X,L(D))=0$ for $i=1,2,3$.
Is anything known about such line bundles? Using Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch its possible to get cubic equation on divisor $D$ like $2D^3+c_2(X)D=12$ which leaves us only vanishing cohomology conditions. Such line bundles are for instance never ample, but maybe there are always finitely many of them or something?

Comment: I do not understand, why it can not be ample?